# how to write metadata into Excel workbooks using Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[MetaData Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCieg.png)
[Expected File Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCieg.png)

Need to write custom data into excel file using Apache POI.I am using POI 3.1.1 version jar. This is my code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sample);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
POIXMLProperties props = workbook.getProperties();

/* Let us set some core properties now*/
POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProp = props.getCoreProperties();
coreProp.setCreator("Thinktibits"); //set document creator
coreProp.setDescription("set Metadata using Apache POI / Java");
coreProp.setCategory("Programming"); //category

/* Finally, we can set some custom Properies */
POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties custProp = props.getCustomProperties();
custProp.addProperty("Author", "Thinktibits");// String
custProp.addProperty("Year", 2014);     // Number Property
custProp.addProperty("Published", true); //Yes No Property
custProp.addProperty("Typist", "tika");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sample);
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Can anyone help me where it went wrong in my code to get the expected custom tab?

Comment: I thing you should tell us where your code went wrong, so we can help you. I think you should run the code and tell us where the exception is thrown and what the exception is.

Comment: I could not see any exception thrown in the code.And no customproperty created.So i was blank how to proceed further.

Comment: I am not sure, but your code works on my computer. I used  POI 3.16 and poi-oxxml 3.16. Created an Excel (xlsx) Document before. Read the document with your code and run it. on Excel 2011 it shows the properties. Are you reading an xls or xlsx? What Excel you are using?

Comment: Iam Using  POI 3.13 and poi-oxxml 3.16.And Excel 2010.

Comment: you should not use different versions. decide which one you want. I get an exception if I use different versions. Therefore use one for both. Either 3.13 or 3.16 works for me

Comment: Even when i used poi-oxxml 3.13.it didnt work for me..Will try to change the Excel 2010 to Excel 2011.

Comment: So your application is running without an exception? Is the Excel-document the right one you are checking? In my scenario the Excel Document already exists. Try to create a new empty excel document, save it on C: and run your application as I posted it below. Just to try.

Comment: I can see the metadata properties in Details tab.Is it possible to create a custom tab like Details Tab.

Comment: Glad it works. I would appreciate an up-vote/accept. As far as I know you can not create a custom tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here this code works for me with Excel 2011 and XLSX (of course the xlsx needs to be not open in EXCEL):

```
public class ApachePOI {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Mappe1.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        POIXMLProperties props = workbook.getProperties();

        /* Let us set some core properties now */
        POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProp = props.getCoreProperties();
        coreProp.setCreator("Thinktibits"); // set document creator
        coreProp.setDescription("set Metadata using Apache POI / Java");
        coreProp.setCategory("Programming"); // category

        /* Finally, we can set some custom Properies */
        POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties custProp = props.getCustomProperties();
        custProp.addProperty("Author", "Thinktibits");// String
        custProp.addProperty("Year", 2014); // Number Property
        custProp.addProperty("Published", true); // Yes No Property
        custProp.addProperty("Typist", "tika");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Mappe1.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

As dependency I got:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.16</version>
</dependency>
```